# How to apply the rule of absorption correctly to the following logical expressions?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How was the rule of absorption applied to the following logical expression?

$$ (A \land \neg B \land C) \lor (A \lor B \lor \neg C) \lor (\neg A \land B) \equiv (A \lor B \lor \neg C) \lor (\neg A \land B).$$

The step is not really clear to me, and I hope someone can explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using associativity,
$$
(A \wedge \neg B \wedge C) \vee (A \vee B \vee \neg C) \vee (\neg A \wedge B)
= ((A \wedge \neg B \wedge C) \vee A) \vee (B \vee \neg C)\vee (\neg A \wedge B).
$$
Now, by absorption and associativity,
$$(A \wedge \neg B \wedge C) \vee A = (A \wedge (\neg B \wedge C)) \vee A = A,$$
and the expression becomes
$$A \vee (B \vee \neg C)\vee (\neg A \wedge B),$$
which is the desired result, using associativity again.

Comment: I understand, thank you! EDIT: But why is C negated in the first expression?

Comment: @Logik That was a typo of mine, sorry. Anyway, it doesn't affect the result or the reasoning, because it's part of the expression which is "absorbed". I'll edit to the correct expression.

Answer (score 4):

Given associativity of $\lor$, you can just drop parentheses:

$$ (A \land \neg B \land C) \lor (A \lor B \lor \neg C) \lor (\neg A \land B) $$

$$=(A \land \neg B \land C) \lor A \lor B \lor \neg C \lor (\neg A \land B)$$

So now the $A$ terms absorps the $(A \land \neg B \land C)$ term:

$$=A \lor B \lor \neg C \lor (\neg A \land B) $$

And note that the $B$ term will absorp the $(\neg A \land B) $ term:

$$=A \lor B \lor \neg C $$

When you drop unnecessary parentheses, these kinds of simplifications become a lot easier to see!

Comment: Hey, yes its true. I understood it ! Thank you too!

Comment: @Logik You're welcome! :)